# hasPermanentMenuKey() doesn't work

Tags: android

I'm using:

```
if(ViewConfiguration.get(getActivity()).hasPermanentMenuKey()){
        // whatever
    }
```

The case is that in the emulators with Android Studio behaves perfectly on any API, even the 25. But then on the cell phones that do not have the navigation bar on the screen, like the Samsung, does not work. On my Nexus 5 with API 23 if it detects it.

Comment: If it is **SOLVED** then why not just remove this question?

Comment: @azizbekian: it is better to move the answer to the answer box, and self-accept it, so that future readers may benefit from it.

Answer (score 2):

SOLUTION:

```
public boolean hasNavBar (Resources resources)
{
    int id = resources.getIdentifier("config_showNavigationBar", "bool", "android");
    return id > 0 && resources.getBoolean(id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean hasPermanentKeys(Activity activity) {
    //
    int height=0;
    int realHeight=0;

    WindowManager w = activity.getWindowManager();
    Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    d.getMetrics(metrics);
    // since SDK_INT = 1;
     height = metrics.heightPixels;

// includes window decorations (statusbar bar/menu bar)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 17)
        try {
            realHeight = (Integer) Display.class.getMethod("getRawHeight").invoke(d);
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
// includes window decorations (statusbar bar/menu bar)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17)
        try {
            Point realSize = new Point();
            Display.class.getMethod("getRealSize", Point.class).invoke(d, realSize);
            realHeight = realSize.y;
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
    if(height == realHeight){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

This will work for any SDK just we need to pass Activity Context. Since device is not going to change use it in Splash screen and save it in preferences or some static variable. Depending on the above value the view which is getting overlapped, A bottom padding should be given.

```
 private int getNavigationBarHeight() {
    Resources resources = getResources();
    int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
        return resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return 0;
}

if (!havingNavigation) {//there's a navigation bar
        bottomPadding += getNavigationBarHeight();
    }
```

Comment: I try your solution. It works fine. ViewConfiguration.get(getActivity()).hasPermanentMenuKey() is not working with my ASUS Zenphone 4.

Comment: Debug and see, what it is missing?